# How do I get Google to mark my website as "safe" in the search results with a small green icon?

Tags: google-search, security, search-results

Some websites are marked as safe in the Google search results like shown in the image:

[image]

My website and others are not. How do I get this safe mark for my website?

Answer (score 9):

This looks like the output of a browser extension, which means only users with the extension installed will see the badge.

For example, Mcafee SECURE Safe Browsing place a similar badge next to "safe" sites according to TrustedSite.com

You can apply for such a badge at https://www.trustedsite.com/signup?re=addsite

Comment: thank you for the answer. can you tell me more about this website? is it trustworthy?

Comment: My comment should have been more clear that TrustSite is only an example.  Assuming you took this screenshot, you will need to look at the browser extensions that you have installed to determine how the badge was placed there.

Answer (score -4):

Do you notice the website used a *https* protocol? Https are marked as secured not safe and your site can be if you obtain an https certificate.

Comment: Explain why both are https yet only one has the green dot.